# find time in hour from two datetime in asp.net mvc using linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I m working on timesheet module.What my problem is i have table with following fields

```
work_start_time  Datetime
work_end_time    Datetime
and other field
```

now my requirement is i have to calculate total hour submitted till date.

field are save like this format `dd/mm/yy 10:00 AM`

please anybody help me how to find total hour from above two field and sum total hour using LINQ.

any help would be appreciated.

```
int totalhours = (from d in db.timesheetWorkingHours
                             .Where(d=>d.WStartTime.HasValue && d.WEndTime.HasValue)
                             select (d.WStartTime - d.WEndTime).Hours).FirstOrDefault();

its gives error 

'System.Nullable<System.TimeSpan>' does not contain a definition for 'Hours' and no extension method 'Hours' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.TimeSpan>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Subtracting two DateTime objects gives you a TimeSpan http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx and the TotalHours gives what I think  you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the pseudo code. This may help. in your scenario timesheets object you would be getting from the db.

```
IList<Timesheet> timesheets = new List<Timesheet>();
            timesheets.Add(new Timesheet
            {
                work_start_time = new DateTime(2012, 11, 5, 10, 0, 0),
                work_end_time = new DateTime(2012, 11, 5, 19, 0, 0)
            });
            timesheets.Add(new Timesheet
            {
                work_start_time = new DateTime(2012, 11, 5, 10, 0, 0),
                work_end_time = new DateTime(2012, 11, 5, 19, 0, 0)
            });
            int totalhours = 0;
            timesheets.ToList().ForEach(
                p => { TimeSpan ts = p.work_end_time - p.work_start_time; totalhours += ts.Hours; }
            );

            Console.WriteLine(totalhours.ToString());

            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: var hour =(from EventTime in db.timesheetWorkingHours
            select (SqlMethods.DateDiffHour(EventTime.WStartTime, EventTime.WEndTime)));

          var result = hour.Sum(); but its gives error System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] DateDiffMinute(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime], System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.